# Email format broken when sending emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I recently noticed that emails sent out of my school Gmail account were not utilizing the full space for text. For some reason, the body of the email breaks every 10 or so words to a new line. Attached is an example of this:[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Does the same happens when you send an email with formatted text (using italics, bold, fonts of diffent types and sizes, tables, inline images...)?

Comment: Yes. Even if I paste it from word or another application it still formats it in that strange way.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this, because it reminds me of some enterprise settings in Outlook that convert any message to text only.

To see your setting:

1. Click compose
2. Click the three vertical dots at the bottom right of the message window.
3. See if "plain text mode" is checked.

If it is checked then gmail appears to force a newline every ~70 characters.